# Connection string keyword 'server' is not supported in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My college class is working on a project which we have already built several times without error. However, some recent change prompted this error to happen:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
  An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'AdministrationAPI.Data.AppDbContext'.
  System.ArgumentException: Connection string keyword 'server' is not supported. For a possible alternative, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142181.
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String keyword)
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
     at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionFactory.GetPoolGroup(String connectionString)
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.CreateDbConnection()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.CreateDbCommand(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, Guid commandId, DbCommandMethod commandMethod)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
  System.ArgumentException: Connection string keyword 'server' is not supported. For a possible alternative, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142181.
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String keyword)
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
     at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionFactory.GetPoolGroup(String connectionString)
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.CreateDbConnection()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.CreateDbCommand(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, Guid commandId, DbCommandMethod commandMethod)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Connection string keyword 'server' is not supported. For a possible alternative, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142181.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String keyword)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionFactory.GetPoolGroup(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.CreateDbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.CreateDbCommand(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, Guid commandId, DbCommandMethod commandMethod)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1.RoleExistsAsync(String roleName)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\xxx\Documents\GitHub\xxx\xxx\Program.cs:line 102
   at Program.<Main>(String[] args)
PS C:\Users\xxx\Documents\GitHub\xxx\xxx>
```

I don't really know where the issue is. Here's our connection strings:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnectionString": "server=localhost;User Id=root;password=password;database=ourproject;",
    "DefaultConnectionString_Select": "server=localhost;User Id=root;password=password;database=ourproject_application;",
    "SqliteMain": "Data Source=main.db",
    "SqliteProvider": "Data Source=provider.db",
    "OurprojectDB": "Data Source=SQL8005.site4now.net;Initial Catalog=db_a96e9a_ourproject001;User Id=db_a96e9a_ourproject001_admin;Password=mihighschool"
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Well, seems like you are using connection string for MS SQL Server to connect to a SQLite database. Where does this `DefaultConnectionString` come from? And why are you using it when you want to connect to SQLite?

Comment: @derpirscher I wish I knew. We're divided into teams and my team was tasked with something not related to either database.

Answer (score 1):

According to referenced document [SQLite Connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings)

you have to use `Data Source` instead of `Server`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to connect to SQL Server, then replace `Server` with `Data Source`